# Why does this Python if() test always resolve to true?

Tags: python

I was working on my Pokemon: Fire Red text adventure when i encountered a problem. The code is pretty basic, however im not sure as to why it doesn't work.
ive only just started learning to program, so Im not an expert. Here is the code :3

```
startertitle1 = "The GRASS TYPE Pokemon"
startertitle2 = "The FIRE TYPE Pokemon"
startertitle3 = "The WATER TYPE Pokemon"
x = 0
while x == 0:
    print "*** There are three POKEBALLS infront of you, which POKEBALL do you want? Pokeball     (1), (2), or (3)"
    pokeball = raw_input(">>>")
    if pokeball == "1":
        starter = "BULBASAUR"
        startertitle = startertitle1
        print "Are you sure you want to go with "+starter+", "+startertitle+"?[Y/N]"

    elif pokeball == "2":
        starter = "CHARMANDER"
        startertitle = startertitle2
        print "Are you sure you want to go with "+starter+", "+startertitle+"?[Y/N]"

    elif pokeball == "3":
        starter = "SQUIRTLE"
        startertitle = startertitle3
        print "Are you sure you want to go with "+starter+", "+startertitle+"?[Y/N]"

    sure = raw_input(">>>")
    if sure == "Y" or "y":
            print "Oak: I see! "+starter+" is your choice! This Pokemon is really quite energetic!"
            x = x+1
```

thanks in advance for your help :)

**Problem description:**

When the code runs the test `if sure == "Y" or "y":` always resolves to `true` and the line `Oak: I see!...` is always printed, even when I enter `N`. Why is this `if()` test always resolving to true?

Comment: You *must* tell us *WHAT* doesn't work if we are to be able to help you.  No one's going to run your code and try to guess what you're intending it to do.

Comment: oh right, sorry. basically, after the program asks you if you are sure. Even if sure == "N" it will print the 'sure == "Y"' part of the code. (print "Oak: I see!.....")

Comment: im not sure if i've explained it well /

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't specify what the objective/problem is, let me guess:

```
if sure == "Y" or "y":
```

Evaluates to True every time, since "y" is always true.

Hint:
  Try to evaluate the following:

```
if 'y': print 'test'
```

More likely what you want is:

```
if sure == "Y" or sure == "y":
```

Comment: Your statement is read as `if (sure == 'Y') or ('y')`.  If the expression on *either* side of the `or` is true, then the whole expression is true.  It's not immediately clear how Python will evaluate the truthfulness of the expression `'y'`, so you need to know that Python's rules state that any string other than an empty string evaluates to `true`.  An empty string evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if sure == "Y" or "y"
```

to

```
if sure == "Y" or sure == "y"
```

Even better:

```
if sure in ["Y", "y"]
```

Comment: thanks, but can someone tell me why sure == "Y" or "y" doesnt work?

Comment: So your original `if` expression, if (pun unintended) parenthesized would be `if ((sure == "Y") or ("y"))`. That's a [OR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) right there.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the if statement as such:

```
if sure == "Y" or sure == "y":
```

Also, the code is missing a small piece. Namely when one decides not to take the starter they just selected. What you should add is:

```
if sure == "N" or sure == "n":
    print starter + "not selected.\n"
    x = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

at the if statement

if sure == "Y" or "y":

it will only return true. To fix the problem you must do this:

if sure == "Y" or sure == "y":

you should do a similar thing if you want a response when saying no

if sure == "N" or sure == "n":
        print "Oak:....."(whatever you want him to say)